# accessing derby database from eclipse and ij simultaneously

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, derby

I am developing an dynamic web project in eclipse which requires me to connect to a database and display the fields that I have chosen.

I have created a database named javadb. I am able to access the javadb from ij scripting tool and the eclipse IDE  individually but not from both at a time.
When I deploy my web app on tomcat server and run the application which is using the database javadb and when I try to connect to the database through the ij tool using the command 
`connect 'jdbc:derby:javadb';`
the error shown is

```
ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'javadb' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@74b10b, see the next exception for details.
ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/computer/javadb.
```

I am start the apache derby network server using the command

```
java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyrun.jar server start
```

I am only able to access the javadb only after shutting down the server and restarting it.

I am using Eclipse Kepler , Apache derby 10.10 to create database, Apache tomcat 7 as server. Operating system Ubuntu 12.04

Can anyone please help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the embedded configuration, a Derby database can only be accessed by one Java application at a time.

In order to have multiple applications accessing the same Derby database simultaneously, you need to run Derby in a client-server configuration, and ensure that a Derby server is running.

Other than deploying the Derby server, the only other changes you have to make are to change your connection URL and your JDBC class name.

Here's some documentation: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/cadminov17524.html
 and http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/cadminov825266.html

Comment: The driver i am registering is `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` and the URL is `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/javadb` what are the other things that I have to change so that I can access my database `javadb` from eclipse and ij scripting tool at a time.

Comment: You have to specify that JDBC Connection URL from *all* the clients that are connecting, including ij. So change your  ij command, too, so you say "connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/javadb'". Otherwise ij is still trying to connect using the Embedded Driver.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I have to change the url through which  ij connects. This help he solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same exception, and this is what helped me - delete .lck files in the root directory of the database. Delete them after you make sure no other app is accessing the db.